# if new record run python

Tags: python, mysql

This may be a noob-question, but I'll ask it anyway.

I want to set a GPIO on a raspberry when I get a new
row in my database. Is there a good way doing this or should I just have a python-script running all the time polling the db for the last id and check if it's new?

Sorry for the lack of knowledge.

//Martin

Comment: You can use a `trigger` in a SQL database to perform an action after a new row is created.

Comment: You don't have to be sorry for your lack of knowledge... that's why SO is for!

Comment: Something's inserting the data into the db and that "something" should be what notifies your raspberry that it should pull some info from the db. There are solutions which allow MySQL to execute an external program, you can google for `MYSQL UDF SYS_EXEC`. Polling is an inefficient idea, but a viable one. You have 3 options now, I would go with 1st.